# Why is my photo becoming bigger?, Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, image, crop

I am using the AVFoundation to take a photo but when I do the photo image that comes back is more enlarged than the photo I took.

Does anyone know why this would be?

I have the camera in landscape mode.

Below is my code for taking the image and then assigning it to a new variable.

```
    var cropArea:CGRect{
    get{
        let factor = backImage.image!.size.width/view.frame.width
        let scale = CGFloat(1)
        let imageFrame = viewFinder.imageFrame()
        let x = (cropAreaView.frame.origin.x - imageFrame.origin.x) * scale * factor
        let y = (cropAreaView.frame.origin.y - imageFrame.origin.y) * scale * factor
        let width = cropAreaView.frame.size.width * scale * factor
        let height = cropAreaView.frame.size.height * scale  * factor
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
        print(imageData)

        image = UIImage(data: imageData)

        backImage.image = image


        let croppedCGImage = self.backImage.image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: self.cropArea)
        let croppedImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage!)

        self.pictureView.image = croppedImage
```

Comment: I think i have a fix. I set scale to 2 and that seems to have done the trick. Thank you

Comment: You're probably failing to consider point resolution. Points are not the same as pixels in iOS. Your potential scales are from 1-3 these days. If you're comparing to screen resolution, check UIScreen.current.scale.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Rob it gives me something to look into for the future.